# Fire mouseenter on drilldown for highcharts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, highcharts

When using 2 level chart in highchart, if I click on a parent node and then goes to its children, and a child data is lying at the exact position of the parent. it doesn't show a tooltip by default even the cursor is at that position, we need to do either a click or move our mouse.

Steps to reproduce: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/basic/)

1. Click on car
2. Let the mouse be on the child node.

The tooltip is not visible by default.

This works fine on firefox, as firefox fires a mouseenter event by default.

Comment: If you wait until animation end, you will see that tooltip is showed above the child.

Comment: @d_paul no, I need to move/click mouse, to see that tooltip. you can try by keeping the mouse on car and then refresh the page(press F5).

Comment: Same as @d_paul - On Chrome 62: Click "Cars", and *without moving the mouse*, the tooltip changes to "Volkswagen" after a second or so, when the column animation is finished.

Comment: Yes, works on chrome 62. Thanks